# How do I stop Routing Errors errors from causing all sorts of warning?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, error-handling, newrelic

My Rails 4 app on Heroku (currently on unicorn) doesn't have too many errors usually but it gets tons of bad URLs. Whenever a bad URL is entered, the user sees my 404 page and an ActionController::RoutingError is raised in Rails. This gets reported to [Rollbar](https://rollbar.com/docs/notifier/rollbar-gem/) and NewRelic as errors, and they raise the alarms. I'm constantly getting alerts from NewRelic about all these "errors". How do I prevent a routing error from being reported as an error?

(I tried changing a line in newrelic.yml to `ignore_errors: ActionController::RoutingError` but it didn't help.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Server Side Config (determine this on the app's Settings page in New Relic), be sure that `ActionController::RoutingError` is included in the `Ignore these errors` field.

You might also try setting an environment variable on Heroku to ignore errors like this.  For example, `NEW_RELIC_ERROR_COLLECTOR_IGNORE_ERRORS="ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, ActionController::RoutingError"`

Answer (score 8):

Since the other answer takes care of New Relic, the solution in Rollbar is to add the following line into config/initializers/rollbar.rb (see comments in that file for more info):

```
config.exception_level_filters.merge!('ActionController::RoutingError' => 'ignore')
```